# Cinnamon editing

Tags: customization, cinnamon, mint, docky

After some searching, I was left pretty much stranded.
I'm currently working on reworking a few things in Cinnamon desktop environment.

Here's what I need advice on:

- Resizing the Cinnamon panel on the X axis (If I'm thinking correctly)
- Changing the color of the window borders

Here's where I am so far.

Essentially, I need to be able to use Docky along with Cinnamon Panel without interference from the two. I currently have the panel on autohide just so I can operate.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, @karel, for your edit. However, still looking for answers.

Answer (score 0):

For the first point, you need to change the code. Could be possible create an extension to allow what you want to do. Is possible now modify this on an extension after cinnamon 2.6. The other possibility is modify directly the cinnamon current code, but you will lost your change after an update.
For the second, i think is possible modify the gtk theme (is not possible in the cinnamon theme).